# Is it possible to install MongoDB on 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I just want to install MongoDB on my 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop, but i found something on their page that say :

> **PLATFORM SUPPORT**
>   MongoDB only provides packages for 64-bit LTS (long-term support) Ubuntu releases. For example, 12.04 LTS (precise), 14.04 LTS (trusty), 16.04 LTS (xenial), and so on. These packages may work with other Ubuntu releases, however, they are not supported.

This is  [the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to MongoDB official website that said above. Could i still install MongoDB on my laptop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. MongoDB is no longer providing installation packages for 32-bit Linux distributions.

I found this below link can be help full for you. Please check it once.

[mongodb-on-32-bit-ubuntu](https://dzone.com/articles/installing-mongodb-on-32-bit-ubuntu-1510)

Answer (score 0):

**Taken from : https://askubuntu.com/questions/772181/how-can-i-install-mongodb-on-32-bit-ubuntu**

```
    download the binary files here or using
```

`curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz`

```
    extract the files

    tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz

    copy extracted files

    mkdir -p mongodb
    cp -R -n mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6/ mongodb

    add it to PATH

    #example in ~/.bashrc
    export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH

note as noted in mongodb using this method will have some limitation

"This 32-bit legacy distribution does not include SSL encryption and is limited to around 2GB of data. In general you should use the 64 bit builds."

but in the end it is up to you.
```